# не находит реальное устройство Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Сегодня я наконец покорил Andoid Studio 3 , все летает, программа поет, а не работает. Одно но... не работает эмулятор. Решил просто подключить свой смартфон Sony E115. Но Studio пишет not connecting device. Все нужные Tools я поставил. Режим разработчика на смартфоне включен. в чем дело не пойму. Подскажите а???

Comment: А драйвера для устройства установились успешно?

Comment: Попробуйте разные варианты подключения на устройстве. У меня один смартфон подключался только в режиме "камера" например. Если не поможет - гуглите "adb подключение неподдерживаемого устройства"

Comment: Проблема была с драйвером. Обновил. Все встало. Всем спасибо))